# Adding System user to local group

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to add NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM to local groups (Schema Admins and Enterprise Admins specifically). However, it says that changes to the user's group membership are not effective until the next the user logs on. Is there way to log on as the System user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A computer's SYSTEM user "logs on" when the computer authenticates to its domain controller. Restarting the computer will add those group memberships to the machine account.

Note that, if you're trying to grant those privileges to an application running as SYSTEM on a certain computer, you should add its specific machine account to the group. Machine account names are just the name of the respective computer with a `$` at the end. For instance, a computer named `CATACLYSM` would have a machine account entitled `CATACLYSM$`.

(I'm assuming you're actually in a domain environment because of the groups you're adding the user to.)